# sh -c '...' sh {} not working when using if statement and having ' in the filename

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, find

I have the following simplified script:

```
find /home/cas/plex-media/series/ -type f ! -name "*.srt" -exec sh -c '
    file=$1
    if [ if-statement using $file ]; then 
        echo "true"
    else 
        echo "false"
    fi
' find-bash {} \;
```

The script works perfectly, unless there is a `'` in the file name (e.g. `/home/cas/plex-media/series/The Legend Of Korra/Season 4/The Legend of Korra - S04E11 - Kuvira's Gambit.mkv`), in which case I get the following error:

```
find-bash: 1: [: =: unexpected operator
```

I don't know how to fix it. When the filename does't have a `'` in it, the script works perfectly.

Edit to answer questions:
Here is the complete script. I simplified it first because the if statement is very very long. But you wanted the complete thing so here it is. Normally it is one long line, but I broke it apart so that you can read it more easily.

```
find /home/cas/plex-media/series/ -type f ! -name "*.srt" -exec bash -c '
file="$1"; 
echo "$file"; 
thetvdb=$(GET http://192.168.2.15:32400/library/sections/2/all?X-Plex-Token=HfXBs23FhKBGj3msHjAz | grep $(curl -sSL https://thetvdb.com/series/$(echo "$file" | grep -o "series/.*/Season" | grep -o "/.*/" | sed "s|/||g" | sed "s| |-|" | sed "s| |-|" | sed "s| |-|" | sed "s| |-|" | sed "s| |-|" | sed "s| |-|" | sed "s|(||" | sed "s|)||") | grep -A 1 "<strong>TheTVDB.com Series ID</strong>" | grep -E -o "[0-9]{1,9}")); 
themoviedb=$(GET http://192.168.2.15:32400/library/sections/2/all?X-Plex-Token=HfXBs23FhKBGj3msHjAz | grep $(curl -sL https://www.themoviedb.org/search?query=$(echo "$file" | grep -o "series/.*/Season" | grep -o "/.*/" | grep -E -o "[A-Z].*[a-z]" | sed "s| |+|g") | grep "href=\"/tv/.*\"><h2>" | head -n1 | grep -oE "/tv/[0-9]{1,9}" | grep -oE "[0-9]{1,9}")); 
if [[ 
$(GET http://192.168.2.15:32400
        $(GET http://192.168.2.15:32400
                $(GET http://192.168.2.15:32400
                        $(echo 
                                $(if [[ -z "$thetvdb" ]]; 
                                then echo "$themoviedb" | grep -o "key=\".*/children\" guid"; 
                                else echo "$thetvdb" | grep -o "key=\".*/children\" guid"; 
                                fi)
                         | grep -o "/.*/children"
                         )?X-Plex-Token=HfXBs23FhKBGj3msHjAz | grep "index=\"$(echo "$file" | grep -Eo "/Season [0-9]{1,3}" | grep -Eo "[0-9]{1,3}")\"" | grep -o "key=\"/.*/children\" parentRatingKey" | grep -o "/.*/children"
                )?X-Plex-Token=HfXBs23FhKBGj3msHjAz | grep -B 2 "$file" | grep -o "key=\".*\" parentRatingKey" | grep -Eo "/.*/[0-9]{1,9}"
        )?X-Plex-Token=HfXBs23FhKBGj3msHjAz | grep -o "streamType=\"3\"" | head -n1
) = "streamType=\"3\"" ]]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi' find-bash {} \;
```

I can understand it if you can't understand it completely. So I'll explain it a bit.

The purpose of the script is that it takes every media file in my series folder and checks if it has subtitles. Doesn't matter if they're integrated or external. I use the Plex api to go to the information page about the file and see if `streamType="3"` is there, which means that there is a subtitle.

It first sets the variables `thetvdb` and `themoviedb`. Then it loads the api page of all the series I have in my plex media server. It searches the correct series that the file is from (for this we need those variables). Then grabs the key for that series.

Then it makes another api request with that key, which gives you info about the series and it's seasons. Then it grabs the season the file is from and grabs the key.

Then it does another request with that new key, leading to a page about the season and episodes in it. Then it searches for the episode and grabs the key.

Another request is then made with that key, giving info about the episode. And then grabs `streamType="3"`. If the output of all that is equal to `streamType="3"`, it echo's true. If that string wasn't present (aka the file doesn't have subtitles), the result of the whole thing will be empty because it couldn't grep the string. Which isn't equal to `streamType="3"`

Comment: use double bracket `[[ expression ]]` instead.

Comment: We need to see exactly what is `if-statement using $file`. The problem comes from there after all.

Comment: I cannot reproduce, please give use the if-statement.

Comment: @pLumo i have answered your question in my edit of the original post.

Comment: Wow.... Better use a script. And then run `-exec ./script.sh {} \;`

Comment: So you suggest removing `find /home/cas/plex-media/series/ -type f ! -name "*.srt" -exec bash -c` and `find-bash {} \;` and running `find /home/cas/plex-media/series/ -type f ! -name "*.srt" -exec ./script.sh {} \;`?

Answer (score -1):

If `$1` contains `'` character, then that `'` ends the quoted command `'file=$1; ...`. Everything that is after `'` is outside of the `-c` parameter. That produces the error. Try quoting `$1` in double quotes: `'file="$1"; ...`. Also quote `$file` in double quotes within the `if` command.

Comment: double quoting all the `$1` and `$file` didn't help. Using double brackets (together with double quoting), as suggested by bac0n, made it worse. Now I get the error `find-bash: 1: [[: not found`, everytime. Even when there isn't a `'` in the name.

Comment: sure, `sh` has no `[[`, you can use `bash -c`.